# Reshaping a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I've got a matrix in matlab that's 28x28x10000. I'm looking to reshape it into a matrix that's 10000*784, with each 28x28 submatrix being squeezed into a row. So I tried

```
reshape(mat, 10000, 784)
```

While this does give me a matrix of the correct shape, the values aren't correct. Does anyone know of another way to do this, preferably without for loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reshape` take elements column-wise from the matrix.  For your purpose, that means that if you rearrange the dimensions of your original matrix (using [permute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)), you can use reshape like you already are:

```
reshape(permute(mat,[3 1 2]), 10000, []);
```

The `[3 1 2]` argument to `permute` means use the 3rd dimension as the 1st, then the original 1st as the new 2nd, and the original 2nd dimension as the new 3rd one, giving you a `10000x28x28` matrix.  Each column contains 10000 elements, so taking column-by-column like reshape does will work give you what you want.