# Change a multidimensional vector to two dimensional vector matlab

Tags: matlab

A is a multidimensional vector 3x3x3. I want to change it to be 9x3 vector. How can I do this in matlab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reshaping a matrix in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102216/reshaping-a-matrix-in-matlab), [How do I resize a matrix in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793574/how-do-i-resize-a-matrix-in-matlab), [Reshape 3d matrix to 2d matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256925/reshape-3d-matrix-to-2d-matrix) and many more...

Comment: I can understand the closevotes, but why downvoting? The question is clear, and finding the solution is not trivial without knowing the right keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function.

`B = reshape(A,9,3);`

Answer (score 1):

```
vector2D = cat(2,vector3D(:,:,1),vector3D(:,:,2),vector3D(:,:,3))
```

or

```
vector2D = cat(1,vector3D(:,:,1),vector3D(:,:,2),vector3D(:,:,3))
```

The previous will arrange the 2D vectors along rows, while the later will arrange them allong colums